# onResume después de usar finish()

Tags: android, activity

Buenas, tengo una duda relacionada con el ciclo de vida de una actividad, es la siguiente:

Tengo dos actividades, paso de la 1ª a la 2ª y una vez estoy en la 2ª hago un `finish()` para volver a la 1ª. Al volver a la 1ª, entra en el `onResume()` de esta actividad y ahora viene mi pregunta, ¿Hay alguna manera de saber si se ha entrado en el `onResume()` porque se ha hecho un `finish()` para volver a esta?

> Es para diferenciar si se viene de un `startActivity()` o de un
>   `finish()`

Comment: Cuando dices que pasas de la 2da a la 1era `activity` por medio de un `finish()` lo haces por medio del `back button` o cómo? Considera agregar un poco de código respecto a como te mueves por ambas `activitys` para buscar una solución de manera más práctica con lo que llevas.

Comment: @JoriusR el botón de retroceso hace por defecto el `finish()` a no ser que lo sobreescribas el método y lo cambies.  Y paso a la 2ª actividad con un `startActivity()` y vuelvo a la 1ª con un `finish()`

Comment: deberías agregar tu código, para tener más claro lo que haces y lo que deseas hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Hay alguna manera de saber si se ha entrado en el onResume() porque
>   se ha hecho un finish() para volver a esta?
>
> Es para diferenciar si se viene de un startActivity() o de un finish()

**[onResume()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) de la Activity se llama siempre cuando tu Activity obtiene el enfoque nuevamente**, es independiente de si "viene de un `startActivity()` o de un `finish()`".

Puedes revisar el ciclo de vida de la Activity, puedes ver que [onResume()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) es llamado cuando el usuario regresa a la Activity:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De hecho en realidad no regresaste de un propiamente mediante `finish()`, este método se llamo en la Activity que previamente cerraste (2ª).

@borjis No vuelves a la 1ª con un `finish()`, simplemente estas terminando la 2ª por esta razón ves la 1ª `Activity`.

---

Me parece que hay confusión en cuanto a los conceptos:

**[startActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent))** : inicia una nueva `Activity`, la cual será posicionada en el nivel superior de la pila de Activities.

**[finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish())** : termina una `Activity`.

---

Si lo que deseas es saber de que Activity estas "regresando" te sugiero iniciar la `Activity` mediante: [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: @Elanasys en conclusión, no se puede saber en el método `onResume()` de donde "proviene", verdad?

Comment: Son cosas diferentes por ejemplo en tu caso abres la Activity (2ª) mediante startActivity() y esta misma la finalizas mediante finish(). Si lo que deseas es saber de que Activity estas "regresando" te sugiero [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)  me gustaría saber que deseas realizar para que realicemos sugerencias.

Comment: A ver, sabía que el finish lo que hace es terminar la actividad y que la saca de la pila  de actividades pero me interesaba saber si había alguna manera de saber si al entrar en el onResume() era porque venía de utilizar un startActivity() o de usar un finish(), que es verdad, que lo que hace es terminar la actividad anterior, me expresé mal xD. Pero veo que es imposible a  no ser que utilices el startActivityForResault(); que es lo que hago a veces. Gracias !