# Refrescar actividad desde una actividad posterior

Tags: java, android

Tengo una app en la que lanzo una actividad de ajustes en l que se puede configurar el w-fi y la url a mostrar en la primera actividad. El problema es que, al retroceder y volver a la app del principio, los cambios no se muestran automáticamente.¿ Cómo lo puedo hacer?, ¿Hay alguna manera de detectar que ha vuelto de la segunda actividad? Si la hubiera, ¿Valdría con ejecutar este código al detectar que ha vuelto a la primera actividad?

```
public void RestartActivity()
    {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Sin hacer esto,, ¿Habría alguna posibilidad de volver a ejecutar el OnCreate?

Comment: Si no me equivoco, lo que quieres hacer es, al volver de una actividad a su actividad "padre" que se reflejen los cambios hechos en la actividad "hija". Para eso inicia la actividad hija con startActivityForResult() y al volver tienes que sobrescribir el método OnActivityResult(). En este método es donde haces los cambios que quieres que se reflejen

Comment: podrias lanzar un startactivityforresult visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sobre escribe el metodo [`onResume()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) del activity que se ejecuta cuando el `Activity` pasa a estado activo otra vez:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

   //...


  @Override
  public void onResume()
  {
    // ejecuta el codigo aqui...
  }
}
```

En tu caso, estabas en el `Activity_A` e iniciaste el `Activity_B` y asi que la `Activity_A` se inactiva. Ahora bien, cuando vuelves a `Activity_A`, el metodo `onCreate` no se ejecuta otra vez porque ya fue creada(recuerda que esta inactiva, no finalizada), por lo que se ejecuta el metodo `onResume()`. Esto siempre y cuando no ejecutemos el metodo `finish()` que termina el `Activity`.

Comment: Perdona pero en qué activity dices que debería usar en el "onResume"? Porque por tu explicación entendía que en la segunda, pero el ejemplo está en Mainactivity, por lo que creo que no lo he entendido bien del todo.

Comment: Es para utilizarlo en el primer Activity

Answer (score 3):

> El problema es que, al retroceder y volver a la app del principio, los
>   cambios no se muestran automáticamente.

Si regresas a una `Activity` cargada previamente se llama el método `onResume()`, es aquí donde puedes agregar el código necesario para la actualizacion, esto lo puedes ver en [el ciclo de vida de la Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#alc)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ¿Hay alguna manera de detectar que ha vuelto a la actividad?

puedes ver en el sitio varias **[preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34424/onresume-despu%C3%A9s-de-usar-finish)** donde se hace referencia a esto.

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

   //Carga Activity. 

}
```